# Automatic slave reconfiguration after updating master

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, percona-server

I have development mysql master and slave servers and a prod server. I need to set up regular (once a week) syncronization of dev and prod databases. It would be easy for me to use **prod# mysqldump > dump.sql** and **dev-master# mysql < dump.sql** as it won't break replication, but having a 170Gb base it is not very good idea.
So the question is if there's a proper way to re-enable replication after re-writing database on master. Will it work if I just re-write database on both master and slave and hope no bin-log errors occure?

Upd: percona-server-server-5.6, InnoDB/Barracuda are used.

Comment: Please add mysql in tag.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for myself is:
stop both master and slave
remove logs
replace ib* files and /var/lib/mysql/mybase/* with files from prod backup
start mysql on master
start mysql on slave with --skip-slave-start, then SLAVE RESET; SLAVE START;

Not sure if this is correct, but it works for now.